# Strange PHP issue

Tags: php, function

My function looks like that

```
protected function make_js_link($list, $folder, $parentdir = "js") {
        $links = array();

        $list = explode(',', $list);

        foreach ($list as $name) {
            $dir = $parentdir . "/";
            if (is_string($folder))
                echo $folder . "/";
            $links[] = '<script src="' . $dir . trim($name) . '.js"></script>' . "\n";
        }

        echo implode(" ", $links);
    }
```

So when js file located in `$parentdir` I'm calling like that

```
            $this->make_js_link('ckeditor', 0, 'incl/editor');
```

If file located in `parentdir/another_dir`, then calling like that

```
            $this->make_js_link('jquery', 'adapters', 'incl/editor');
```

The problem is, PHP escapes this part in both cases: even if I have folder variable with exact string value:

```
        if (is_string($folder))
            echo $folder . "/";
```

Where I did wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "_escapes this part_"?

Comment: @penartur doesn't echo  echo $folder . "/"; even if $folder has exact string value

Comment: @epic_syntax did you try to add surrounding brackets `if(..){` echo .... `}` ?

Comment: Are you sure you want to `echo` it rather than append it to `$dir`; and are you checking for what have been echoed rather than what path is stored in a `<script/>`s `src` attribute? Also, in this case i'd recommend you to use `if($folder !== null)` instead of `if(is_string($folder))` (and calling it as `$this->make_js_link('ckeditor', null, 'incl/editor');`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did `echo` instead of

```
$dir = $parentdir . "/";
if (is_string($folder))
   $dir.= $folder . "/";
```